# configure kubectl to reach cluster on docker

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I'm facing an interesting challenge, I'm trying to run kubectl in a docker image with a proper configuration, to reach my cluster.

I've been able to create the image, `kubecod`

```sh
    FROM ubuntu:xenial
    
    WORKDIR /project
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl
    
    RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.21.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
    
    RUN chmod +x ./kubectl
    
    RUN mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    
    ENTRYPOINT ["kubectl"]
    #
    CMD ["version"]
```

When I run the image, the container is functionning correctly, giving me the expected answer.

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.2", GitCommit:"f5743093fd1c663cb0cbc89748f730662345d44d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-16T13:41:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.9-eks-d1db3c", GitCommit:"d1db3c46e55f95d6a7d3e5578689371318f95ff9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-10-20T22:18:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

However, my aim is to create an image with the kubectl connecting to my node. Reading the [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#verify-kubectl-configuration), I need to add a configuration file in the following folder `~/.kube/config`

I've created another Dockerfile to build another image, `kubedock`, with the proper config file and the creation of the requisite directory, `.kube`

```sh
FROM ubuntu:xenial

#setup a working directory
WORKDIR /project 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl

RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.21.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl

RUN chmod +x ./kubectl

RUN mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

#create the directory 
RUN mkdir .kube

#Copy the config file to the .kube folder
COPY ./config .kube

ENTRYPOINT ["kubectl"]

CMD ["cluster-info dump"]
```

However, when I run the new image in a container, I have the following message

```sh
me@os:~/_projects/kubedock$ docker run --name kubecont kubedock
Error: unknown command "cluster-info dump" for "kubectl"
Run 'kubectl --help' for usage.
```

Not sure what I'm missing.

Any hints are welcomed.

Cheers.

Comment: For this to work against EKS you need not just the `kubectl` binary but also the AWS CLI, _and_ the user's `~/.kube/config` file, _and_ a current valid set of AWS credentials.  That's a lot of host/user context to be pushing into an isolated Docker container.  Installing the Kubernetes and AWS CLI tools on the host might be much easier.

Comment: @DavidMaze I only need the `~/.kube/config` as we setup some in-house config; There is no need for the AWS cli and also no need for AWS credentials as the in-house system, is taking care of everything minus the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that

```sh
    CMD ["cluster-info","dump"]
```

Or when there is a space in the `kubectl` command line, separate it with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me where your K8s cluster is running,
If you run your cluster in GKE you will need to run something like:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER_NAME --zone $CLUSTER_ZONE
```

Which will create the ~/.config/gcloud tree of files in the users home directory.

On AWS EKS you will need to setup ~/.aws/credentials and other IAM settings.

I suggest you post the details of where your K8s cluster is running and we can take it from there.

PS maybe if you mount/copy the host home directory of a working user into the docker it will work.